# How to catch pages liked on page load with facebook JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi I want to get if liked from facebook like button on page load. I am trying to do fb graph api with user_likes permission works fine. I cant get this permisson from facebook they said that our app doesn't need this permission for its current functionality. Can I get liked or unliked on page load without user-likes permission ? Here is my code example with user_likes permission.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'xxxxxxx',
  status     : true,
  xfbml      : true
});
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
   function(response) {
     window.location.href = 'xyz.com';
   }
);

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
  function(response) {
     <!-- alert('You UNliked the URL: ' + response); -->
     window.location.href = 'xxx.com';
  }
);
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        FB.api(
          '/me/likes/xxxxx',
          'GET',
          {},
          function(response) {
            if(response.data[0])
            {
                alert(response);
                window.location.href = 'xyz.com';
            }
          }
        );
    });
};
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=xxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: see my answer. what for do you need to know the like status? there are some important limitations for that, that´s why i am asking.

Comment: Thank you , I always follow devils-heaven.com.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can´t get the like status without the `user_likes` permission. You should also consider checking for the login status before doing an API call:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        //user is authorized
        FB.api(...);
    } else {
        //user is not authorized
    }
});
```

Source: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/